# Bash script - Adding/Subtracting 1 from file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, counter

This is what I'm trying to do:

I want to make a script that i can invoke either with `counter_use in` or    `counter_use out`. If i type `in` i want a counter to add +1 to the numeric value inside a file called "counter", if I type `out` i want to subtract 1 from the file.

I also want the script to output `Logged in` if the value in counter are equal to or higher than 1 and `Not logged in` if the counter is equal to 0.

The last part is runnig if i hard code the counter to a specific number. The problem is the first part.

```
echo "In or out?"

read input > counterFile

if grep -q "in" counterFile
    then //what should I do here so that it adds +1 to a file called 
counter?

elif grep -q "out" counterFile
    then //what should I do here so that it subtracts -1 to a file called 
counter?

if [ $counter -ge 1 ]
    then
        echo "Logged in"

elif [ $counter -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Not logged in"

else
        echo "Wrong input"

fi
```

Answer (score 2):

[romaric crailox's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43324304/45375) contains many useful pointers, but the code can be streamlined to become a more idiomatic (Bash) solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create the counter file on demand.
[[ -f counter ]] || echo 0 > counter

# Prompt until valid input is received.
while read -p 'In or out? ' input; do

  case $input in
    'in')
      # Update the counter file by incrementing the number it contains.
      perl -i -ple '++$_' counter
      break # valid input received, exit the loop
      ;;
    'out')
      # Update the counter file by decrementing the number it contains.
      perl -i -ple '--$_' counter
      break # valid input received, exit the loop
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid input." >&2  # echo error to *stderr*
      # Stay in the loop to prompt again.
      ;;    
  esac

done

# Read the updated counter file and echo the implied status.
counter=$(< counter)
if (( counter >= 1 )); then
  echo 'Logged in.'
elif (( counter == 0 )); then
  echo 'Not logged in.'
else
  echo "Invalid state: counter is $counter" >&2
fi
```

Note:

- The use of `case ... esac` to handle multiple conditions more succinctly than an `if ... elif ... fi` statement.
- Outputting  error messages to *stderr* with `>&2`
- Use of a `perl` command to update file `counter` in place:

  - `-i` activates in-place updating
  - `-ple` automatically `p`rints the (modified) input line, `-l` adds intelligent newline handing, and `-e` specifies the `e`xpression (script) to run (the following argument)
  - `++$_` / `--$_` then simply increments / decrements the input line at hand (`$_`), which, thanks to `-p`, gets output automatically, and, thanks to `-i`, written back to the original file (loosely speaking; a new file is created that replaces the original).
- Use of arithmetic evaluation (`(( ... ))`) to test numbers.

Comment: Thanks for this better solution

Answer (score 1):

First problem is the use of read command. Try this

```
read -p "in or out ?" input
```

- -p option is to specifie something to print to stdout
- input is the name of shell script variable that will store user input

After this command, input variable will be `in` or `out`.
Then you can test if input is `in` or `out` with an `if` expression :

```
if [ "$input" == "in" ] [...]
```

To add or substract 1 to value inside counter file, you can retrieve current value Inside file, add or substract 1 and write new value Inside file (I'm not sure you want to write new value. Try this :

```
crt_val=$(cat ./counter)
new_val=$(( crt_val + 1 ))
echo $new_val > ./counter
```

Counter file have to be present, so you can add, at the beginning of script

```
if [ -e ./counter ] ; then echo "0" > ./counter ; fi
```

Finally, code can be this :

```
# user entry
read -p "in or out ? " input

# initialize counter file
if [ ! -e ./counter ] ; then echo "0" > ./counter ; fi

# Doing what user entry ask to do
if [ "$input" == "in" ]
then
  echo "in"
  crt_val=$(cat ./counter)
  new_val=$(( crt_val + 1 ))
  echo $new_val > ./counter
elif [ "$input" == "out" ]
then
  echo "out"
  crt_val=$(cat ./counter)
  new_val=$(( crt_val - 1 ))
  echo $new_val > ./counter
else
  echo "Wrong input, try in or out"
  exit 1
fi

# Output
if [ $new_val -ge 1 ]
then
  echo "Logged in"
elif [ $new_val -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Not logged in"
else
  echo "Wrong counter value"
fi
```

Be carefull, user entry have to be exactly `in` or `out` (case sensitive), and have to be no empty. To protect empty answer, try `if [ "x$input" == "xin" ] [...]`

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "In or out?"

read c <&0  # reads from stdin file descriptor &0 is stdin

if [[ $c == 'In' ]] || [[ $c == 'in' ]];  
then
counter=$(<counter.txt) # reads counter from file
let "counter = counter +1"  # increases variable
echo "$counter" > 'counter.txt' # write new value to file overwriting the old
elif [[ $c == 'Out' ]] || [[ $c == 'out' ]];
then
counter=$(<counter.txt) # reads from file
let "counter = counter -1"
#echo "$counter" > 'counter.txt'
else
echo "wrong input..."
fi
```

[Write to file, but overwrite it if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676459/write-to-file-but-overwrite-it-if-it-exists)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash/706683

http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php

Comment: This doesn't really reliably count, as you have a race condition. You would need to lock the counter file during update.

Comment: can you explain this ?

Comment: You read the counter file, and later you write the updated counter file. If a second process runs this script simultaneously, it could read the counter file between your reading and your writing, and hence doesn't see your updated value yet.

Comment: when i have free time i will add a version that locks the file with `flock` utility  ( https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506857/locking-files-in-bash) you can edit the answer if you want ...